# How to get Deep Freeze Enterprise Console to report the PC (local) it's installed on?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, console, deep-freeze

This is Jan Sher, I simply wanted to know how I could get my own Computer to report into the Console of Deep Freeze Enterprise. I did install Deep Freeze by the Workstation Install program created in the Deep Freeze Administrator, but it still doesn't show my Computer on it. The reason why I want to do this is because at times the Deep Freeze icon in the Taskbar disappears, which as far as I know now, that you cannot uninstall it without unfreezing it first (help on that would also be appreciated, in case you could uninstall even when it's frozen). The advantage of having your Computer showing up in the Console is that you get to change the Deep Freeze state on the top-left of the Console other than "only" doing it from the Taskbar, which as I've said, gets problematic. Thanks in advance for your replies.

By the way, Deep Freeze gives me and my Team absolute guarantee that our systems are protected even in a meltdown. Also, we get to save tons of time that gets wasted in trying to get the Computers up and running again when things go bad, you know how that is.

Here is what the Console looks like without my PC:

[image: What the Console looks like without my PC.]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same kind of issue before few months. After connecting with Faronics Support they guided me as follows about it:

Make sure the port 7725 is opened up on your Console machine for inbound and outbound traffic across TCP and UDP protocols.

Next make sure you are actually able to ping the workstation from the Console machine and vice versa.

If the icon is disappearing from the workstation, it could be a different issue altogether. If you have an antivirus, exclude the C:\Program Files\Faronics from the real time scanning or protection.

If the issue continues, I would recommend you to get in touch with Faronics Support and they'll simply remote in and assist you with your issue.

Regards,
Rubert Cornell

Answer (score 0):

When you create the seed and the exe using the DeepFreeze admin console there is an option to select LAN or LAN/WAN access on the Advanced-Options tab; you select Lan/Wan and put in the ip address of the DeepFeeeze console PC and that’s it really. It will let you see your pc's in your console screen. I do this and change port from 7725 to 7726 and it really work